# How to map service factory PIDs to their `ObjectClassDefinition`

Tags: osgi

In OSGi R6 I desire to programmatically validate user-supplied String configuration properties plus a service factory PID against what is supported by whatever configurable `@Component` (or `ManagedServiceFactory`) that declares it configures this PID, e.g. `@Component(configurationPid=some.service.factory.pid, ...)`. Additionally, I want to somehow convert valid String properties to their appropriate property types. Looking through the OSGi Compendium, it seems the Metatype Service is what I'm looking for.

If that's correct, given the following:

- Applicable components uses component property types to specify their configuration
- Component property types are annotated with `@ObjectClassDefinition`
- Components are annotated with `@Designate`, mapping it to the applicable `@ObjectClassDefinition`

Is this the most straightfoward way to map factory PIDs to their `ObjectClassDefinition`:

- Call `BundleContext.getBundles()`. For each bundle, call `MetaTypeService.getMetaTypeInformation(Bundle)`.
- For each returned `MetaTypeInformation` call `MetaTypeInformation.getFactoryPids()` and filter on the factory PIDs I care about.
- For applicable `MetaTypeInformation`, call `MetaTypeInformation.getObjectClassDefinition(String, String)` to obtain the `ObjectClassDefinition`, using either a default or specific locale.

(Tangential, the above seems expensive to perform each time, so caching bundle IDs, mapping them to associated factory PIDs, and keeping the cache up-to-date somehow seems appropriate.)

Or, is there some other OSGi magic that can be programmatically queried with a service factory PID, which returns something that gets to some `ObjectClassDefinition` quicker than the above process?

### Update 1

Stepping back, I'm writing a CRUD-wrapper around `ConfigurationAdmin` for each of my configurable components. I'm trying to avoid `createFoo`, `deleteFoo`, `updateFoo`, `createBar`, ... My application happens to be amenable to URIs. So my working approach was to use Metatype Service, pass in a parsed URI query (`Map<String, List<String>>`), and then utilize Metatype Service to validate and reconstruct these values, circling back to the OP. (On the side, seems like a not-pretty hack to me.)

Another approach was to use `aQute.bnd.annotations.metatype.Configurable.createConfigurable(Class, Map)`, which I preferred more! Until I saw [this bnd GitHub comment](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues/727#issuecomment-215395622):

> The bnd metatype annotations are deprecated in bnd 3.2 and will be removed in bnd 4.0. These annotations are replaced by the OSGi metatype annotations.

So I didn't want to rely on that package if it's going away soon. I looked at what Felix does and didn't want to use their equivalent `Configurable` class. I'm all ears on different approaches!

### Update 2

Reducing this more, I'd like to validate potentially user-supplied key/values configuration properties to ensure they're applicable for some configuration pid, prior to calling `ConfigurationAdmin.createFactoryConfig`. Maybe this is overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once created a class that takes the configuration class, creates a proxy, and then uses this proxy to get the name of the method and the type. It was used something like this:

```
 ConfigHelper<Config> helper = new ConfigHelper( Config.class, "my.pid");
 int port = helper.get().port(); // get the configuration
 helper.set( helper.get().port(),  1000);
 helper.update();
```

The proxy you get from the `get` would record the method when one of the methods is called. On the `set` method it would use the last called proxy method to identify the property. It would then convert the given value to the property type based on the method's return value. The bnd converter is ideal for this but I think Felix now has a standard OSGi converter. (Which is based on the ideas of the bnd converter.)

The method name is then used as the property. The name mangling necessary is defined in an OSGi spec. This allows you to use underscores, Java keywords, and dotted names.

So this would allow you to roundtrip configurations. No worry about the types, they will automatically fall in their place.

**Updated** This is updated after I understood the question better

**Updated 2** Added an example at https://github.com/aQute-os/biz.aQute.osgi.util/tree/master/biz.aQute.osgi.configuration.util

Comment: Hi Peter! I don't think I communicated myself clearly. Using the example above, given only the implicit configuration pid `"MyComponent"`, how can some other component in some other bundle dynamically map this configuration pid to an `ObjectClassDefinition` instance?

Comment: I updated the OP to reflect the root desire. This all might be a red herring, or not. I dunno :-/

Comment: `ConfigHelper` seems like it would solve my needs; please do post the code somewhere!

Comment: Why not use the Converter from the OSGi specification? https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/util.converter.html